# Como adicionar uma class a uma div quando esta está activa, para que mude de cor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou a fazer um site baseado em Bootstrap, no qual tenho uma zona de portefólio, em que miniaturas abrem uma respectiva DIV colapsável. Preciso que quando uma DIV colapsável esteja aberta, a respectiva miniatura mude a sua formatação CSS, neste caso de cor.
Tentei adicionar uma class a esta chamada ".cliente_activo" através do meu Javascript, mas como não sou expert nesta última linguagem, não obtive sucesso.
Agradecia que me pudessem ajudar.

O meu protótipo:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7nuT5/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estava bem perto, fiz uma alteração e adicionei uma linha para remover as classes que tivessem sido adicionadas a outros elementos

Testa assim:

```
 $('.panel-heading').on('click', function () {
     var self = this;
     $('.cliente_activo').removeClass('cliente_activo'); // remover a classe em todos os elementos que a tiverem
     $(this).addClass('cliente_activo'); // adicionar a a classe ao elemento que recebeu o clique
     if (!bigMedia) {
         $('.panel-collapse').slideUp();
         $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('collapse');
         $(this).addClass('cliente_activo');
     } else {
         if (conteudo) {
             conteudo.slideToggle(function () {
                 $(this).remove();
                 abrirFechar(self);
                 // retirei daqui
             })
         } else abrirFechar(self);
     }

 });
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/zPbGE/)

Também daria para usar o `aberto` que você já tem no código, [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zPbGE/2/)

Comment: Obrigado, só tu me vens ajudar! :D Agora ficou com dois bugs, em que quando fechamos a div a classe não volta ao ao que estava inicialmente. E em modo ecrã pequeno não quando temos uma div aberta, ao clicarmos no respectivo botão para a fechar, ela fecha e reabre.

Comment: @user3216077: aqui fica: __http://jsfiddle.net/qN46N/__ é assim que devia ser?

Comment: @user3216077, já agora uma sugestão: CSS transitions para as cores? :) __http://jsfiddle.net/qN46N/1/__

Comment: Sim é isto. Muito obrigado! :D

Comment: Descobri agora uns bugs que acontecem aquando o redimensionamento do browser com uma div aberta. Em que quando vai de uma dimensão maior para uma mais reduzida, a div fecha-se e a cor do "botão" fica trocada. E quando se redimensiona com uma div aberta para uma dimensão maior (o que será mais frequente acontecer) a div aberta fica por cima das outras, e não dá para fechar, mudando o botão apenas de cor. Muito obrigado pela ajuda mais uma vez.

Comment: @user3216077, e que tal assim: __http://jsfiddle.net/H8kP2/__

Comment: Nem mais! 5 estrelas! Muito obrigado! :D